# Can not get attribute of an object from database with cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I spent hours trying to solve this but I couldn't although it looks easy.
So I created a cakephp project and I created an Api folder where I put my controllers. I wanted to use a model in another controller so I used TableRegistry and it works. my problem is that when I want to get it's id it didn't work .

here is my code :

```
 public function test1()
    {
        $uid = $this->request->data['uid'];
        $carTable = TableRegistry::get('Car');
        $car = $carTable->find()->where(['uid' => $uid]);
        $this->set([
                    'success' => $uid,
                    'car' => $car->id,
                    '_serialize' => ['success','car']
                    ]);
    }
```

when I run this I got :

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: Cake\ORM\Query::$id [APP/Controller/Api/EarthController.php, line 55]
```

but when I just use car without id it works fine !
Any idea ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try executing your query, eg:

```
$car = $carTable->find()->where(['uid' => $uid])->first();
```

Notice that you get means that variable $car is an instance of Cake\ORM\Query, not an Car entity.

Comment: $carTable->find() will return Query object. You can then assign it to variable, and further modify your query. But it will not return any data, until you execute it. You can fire all() on Query to get all records matching your criteria, or first() to get only one. All available options are in CakePHP docs: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html

Comment: so that means that if I only use first() , I put it in a variable , but if I use all() I will need an array right ?!

Comment: Exactly. $query->all() will return an array of entities, and $query->first() will return just one entity.

Comment: @chogath Do not forget to mark this as best answer.